# Jarallax not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I know that the parallax effect with [Jarallax](https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax) alos works on iOS devices. But with my [codepen](https://codepen.io/lupis/pen/KQmqoG) example this doesn't work out.

I have used the recommended cdn:s for the js libraries necessary:

HTML

```
<div class="jarallax">
    <img class="jarallax-img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d2/0a/43/d20a439f0a4957ebb583205d03914aec.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="demo-table">
        <div class="demo-table-cell">
            <h1>Jarallax</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quidem incidunt illo magni, suscipit ad deserunt minima a ipsa distinctio aut fugiat dolore soluta amet tempore, non atque laborum repudiandae necessitatibus natus nihil possimus. ...</p>
</div>

<div class="jarallax">
    <img class="jarallax-img" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-xh9JlLnpuHo/UQaa9W7pDdI/AAAAAAAAL6g/6sQdImTSoYM/s1600/wallpaper-of-a-tiger-swimming-underwater.jpg" alt="">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // object-fit polyfill run
    objectFitImages();

    /* init Jarallax */
    jarallax(document.querySelectorAll('.jarallax'), {
    noIos: false,
});

    jarallax(document.querySelectorAll('.jarallax-keep-img'), {
        keepImg: true,
    });

</script>
```

What have I missed out in my code, as the demo pages for Jarallax do work on iOS devices too.